# Difficulty with various datetime formats and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am puzzled about the various datetime formats used between pandas and numpy, and when one is used as opposed to another.  First, set up a specific date and a date range, both by itself as as a column in a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

all_dates = pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,1,1), dt.date(2020,12,1), freq='MS')
date_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date'])
date_df['Date'] = pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,1,1), dt.date(2020,12,1), freq='MS')
test_date = all_dates[4] - relativedelta(months=1)
```

This behaves as expected:

```
test_date in all_dates
True
```

I understand that the `in` operator when applied to a DataFrame operates on the index, but it's not clear to me why this fails:

```
test_date in date_df['Date'].values
False
```

Especially given that this works:

```
test_date == date_df['Date'].values[3]
True
```

It's very strange to me that the `in` operator fails on the `.values` but a single element test will work.

Can someone explain to me why this behavior happens, and why it is a good and expected thing?

For someone else who is running into this problem in their code and just wants to make it work, what I would consider the expected result is obtained with:

```
test_date.to_numpy() in date_df['Date'].values
True
```

Comment: copying your code I am getting `True` for `test_date in date_df['Date'].values`. Are you sure that is what you meant to type there?

Comment: However, if we try `test_date.to_numpy()==test_date`, we get `True` so why `test_date in date_df['Date'].values` gives `False` - yes it is very strange matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I fully understand the original cause, but this issue has been fixed and is therefore just a curious triviality.

I did not note down my original package versions, but a colleague (and user noah above) reported that they couldn't reproduce the behavior.  I updated everything, and python 3.7.9 and pandas 1.1.3 do NOT show this behavior.  With those versions

```
test_date in date_df['Date'].values
```

returns `True` as one would expect.